# How to place my CSS code representing icons just in front of the CSS class of the word "LIVE" and the Hours of the Timeline?

Tags: css

**My FIRST button code to place just before the word "LIVE":**

```
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ed2121;
  background: rgba(229,97,95,.34);
```

**My SECOND Code to place JUST IN FRONT OF THE TIME (12:25:47):**

```
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 6px;
```

**1 -** I would like to place just in front of the "**LIVE**" Title (whose CSS class is: `td-pulldown-size`) as on the part circled in **BLUE**.

How then to make sure to place my first CSS code above corresponding to the icon is placed just before the Word "**LIVE**" ???

**2 -** And how to use my second CSS Code which represents just **a Point of White color**, so as to place it just in front of the CSS class `et-timeline-date` managing the time at the level of the part surrounded in **GREEN** ???

**In other words, I would like to obtain the following result:**

[image]

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

first

```
<span class="td-pulldown-size">
 <div id="circle">
 </div>
 <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
  <font style="vertical-align: inherit;>LIVE</font>
 </font>
</span>

.td-pulldown-size {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.td-pulldown-size #circle {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #ed2121;
 background: rgba(229,97,95,.34);
}
```

second

```
<div class="et-timeline-date">
 <div id="square">
 </div>
 <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
  <font style="vertical-align: inherit;" 12:25:47 </font>
 </font>
</div>

.et-timeline-date {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.et-timeline-date #square {
 width: 6px;
 height: 6px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #fff;
 margin-left: -10px;
 margin-right: 6px;
}
```

give id to div and sort row.

I think this code is working... If not Im sorry:(

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure your answer is tested before you post it, that way you can be sure you are not guiding OP into a wrong path. Try making a minimal reproducable example where this solution is applied